# New custom intents added to LUIS app are not recognized when LUIS app is connected to Web App bot

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I am trying to make the new custom intents that I created in a LUIS App to be available in a WebApp bot that I created. The intents are working in the LUIS app test pane and also in the bot example query but not with the WebApp bot.

I updated the LuisAppID, LuisAPIKey, LuisAPIHostName in the App Settings of the Web App bot from the Luis App Prediction resource tab.
Please note I am only using the azure portal and LUIS.ai site. I do not have the Visual studio and Emulator installed

Example Query:
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/69485015-9884-4d14-a944-a900e3092025?verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&subscription-key=5b188d8a0ebe498b90c93efcf83aa940&q=

If I type utterances related to the new intent I created, the message in the Test in Web Chat is - Sorry, it looks like something went wrong.

[resourcegroup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhyG0.png) [WebAppbot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEzH1.png) [LUISApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAmy9.png) [Corebot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iuaaa.png)[Existing Dialogs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkQAg.png) [Added Intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wnD9.png)

Comment: "Sorry, it looks like something went wrong." is basically the message that you have when your bot code has an exception, so you will have to debug it. Have you implemented any logic on your bot code to handle the new intents?

Comment: No I did not implement any logic in the code, I updated the LuisAppID, LuisAPIKey, LuisAPIHostName. I have not added any code that needs to be added to account for the new intents in the online editor. Can you pl. suggest the code snippet that needs to be added in the online code editor.
Also when I built and ran the code as is, I notice that the Test in Web Chat option is taking forever with the message "Waiting for the bot to be ready".

Comment: Without knowing how you implemented your bot (created from scratch, based on a template, etc), it's hard to help

Comment: I created from scratch, These are the steps I followed 1. A LUIS App by creating an intent and adding 11 utterances under it and published it 2. Standard Web App bot with the pre-existing dialogs. Added the LUIS App, Key, host name to web app bot. Now I need to add the LUIS App intents to be recognized in the Web App bot. 3. I am using an azure portal with online editor and online LUIS app.

Comment: "Standard Web App bot with the pre-existing dialogs" so it's not built from scratch. Add more details by editing your question please (which template, which language, etc)

Comment: I added a few images, the webapp bot template was "Basic Bot,C#,This bot template contains the following services: Language Understanding and Bot Analytics."

Comment: Were you able to get this working with my answer? If so, please "accept" and upvote it so others can quickly find the answer and I can clear this from my support tracker. If not, let me know how else I can help!

Comment: I agree with the approach, that I should attempt this with the local editor and samples which I am doing now. Since I am new with few rep points my upvote not counted.

Answer (score 1):

@NicolasR's comment is right on the money. You need to adjust your bot code to handle the new intents. You can do this a couple of different ways:

#### 1. Online Editor (not recommended, at all)

Go to `Azure Portal > Your Resource Group > Your App Service > App Service Editor`:

[image]

Then edit the files under `wwwroot`. If your bot is in C#, you'll need to open the console:

[image]

Then execute `dotnet build`, then click Run:

[image]

#### 2. Local Editor (highly recommended)

Go to `Azure Portal > Your Resource Group > Your Web App Bot > Build > Download Source Code`:

[image]

Then, open the code in the editor of your choice (I recommend [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/) or [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) -- both are free), edit the code to account for your new intents, then [Deploy your bot to Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp).

This is much, much better in the long-run as you develop your bot.

---

#### Update

Without actually seeing more of your code, I believe you need to edit your intents into [LuisHelper](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/010532c3477c7ae82ab95f494f395712f0646d93/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot/LuisHelper.cs#L36)

That being said, I'm relatively sure this far more advanced that what you're ready for. I recommend downloading some [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore), and start with the first few to see how they work, then try to get CoreBot working locally.

[Here's some additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55618660/10860086) about getting started.

Comment: Thanks @mdrichardson - MSFT, I will switch to the local editor however for the moment, please can you suggest the code snippet  using online editor to be added to account for the new intents. 
Also when I built and ran the code as is, I notice that the Test in Web Chat option is taking forever with the message "Waiting for the bot to be ready".

Comment: @mvedula Without seeing any of your code or knowing anything about your intents, there is no way that I can possibly suggest what code you can use. Please update your question with this information.

Comment: @mrichardson - MSFT I added a few images into the question, bot template was "Basic Bot,C#,This bot template contains the following services: Language Understanding and Bot Analytics."